# Laravel cache SSH error message

Tags: php, laravel, command-line-interface

I have some troubles with Laravel cache Now for example,
if I change the h1 title in my `index.blade.php` it will still show the
old title.

If I remove the foreach and just put in random html, it
still shows old content and I tried to clear the cache by SSH using this command line

```
php artisan view:clear
```

I got the attached error message

[image: SSH error message]

Comment: Have you tried `php artisan cache:clear` ?

Comment: How is that related to ssh, other than you are using ssh to access the command line?

Comment: Try running `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: First run php artisan view:clear and then php artisan cache:clear

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to SSH. This is either not related to the warning.

You have to run `php artisan view:clear`

This is out of the scope of your issue about view cache, but it's worth mentioning. In order to solve the issue about opcache:

1. Head to php.ini
2. Search for opcache.se, either comment or remove the line
3. Add this line: `zend_extension=opcache.so`

Comment: the error gone away but still the changes are not saved and still keep with old data

Answer (score 0):

**List of the cache clear commands in Laravel**

*Clear Route Cache*

```
php artisan route:cache
```

*Clear Cache Laravel Application*

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

*Laravel Clear Config Cache*

```
php artisan config:cache
```

*Clear View Cache Laravel view (blade) cache*

```
php artisan view:clear
```

*Re-optimized Class*

```
php artisan optimize
```

If not have access SSH or shared hosting servers, then we can also clear the cache by typing the code in route file. Open web.php file and put below code for clear cache of your application :

```
//Clear route cache:
 Route::get('/route-cache', function() {
     $exitCode = Artisan::call('route:cache');
     return 'Routes cache cleared';
 });

 //Clear config cache:
 Route::get('/config-cache', function() {
     $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:cache');
     return 'Config cache cleared';
 }); 

// Clear application cache:
 Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
     $exitCode = Artisan::call('cache:clear');
     return 'Application cache cleared';
 });

 // Clear view cache:
 Route::get('/view-clear', function() {
     $exitCode = Artisan::call('view:clear');
     return 'View cache cleared';
 });
```